# HTTP PUT method structure example

Tags: http

I learn about HTTP and need some examples of HTTP PUT method structure, something like this one for HTTP POST method

[image]

Can you tell me some, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is exactly the same, just the use of the body (replaces the original content) is different.

Guess what, there's a spec: [RFC 2616, Section 9.6](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.9.6).

Comment: I love reading RFCs ;-) More to the point, there is no description or clarification in that RFC section as to whether the request body is contructed like a POST body, or some other format. Mabye that's the header's job? But not specified in that section. Clear as mud, it is.

Comment: Dennis, the payload format is independent of the request method; it depends on the content type.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best examples you're going to get are real world examples.  Download **LiveHTTPHeaders** for Firefox and start recording some of your own traffic to somewhere you know you post data to.  You'll have an endless amount of data to look over that way.